# overlay container div on another

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: When I click on close, the blue container hides and another small container is displayed, which is again used to display the hided container]

[image: small container]

When I click on close, the blue container hides and another small container is displayed, which is again used to display the hidden container.

But, when the small container is being displayed, it also displays a white strip. I don't need the white strip to be displayed. Instead only the small container must be displayed on top, where the brown container is a div with background image

Comment: Can't assume anything without HTML markup or you can create fiddle.

Comment: would you regenerate the issue in jsfiddle? then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Arrow button is set to `position: relative;` now, this is causing the content to flow around it.

You can change the `position` attribute for the arrow to `absolute` with a `top: XXpx;` so that clears the header bar, this will also stop the whitespace appearing. If you share a URL I will be able to update my answer based on your exact code.